# Short story from 70s 80s involving Da Vinci and a bat-like flying machine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story that I remember reading from a book in the 70s or 80s (it was in English and only text) about Leonardo Da Vinci designing a big flying machine together with a friend mathematician (also Italian, I guess). They began building several machines with the shape of a falcon (or an eagle) but none of them was able to fly, mostly because of their heaviness or wing design, but I am not sure about the latter. I don't recall much about what followed but the end of the narration, where, one night, after seen a flock of bats against the full moon, Leonardo resolves to build a small bat-like machine with movable wings that was drop (piloted by Da Vinci) from the top of a cathedral and landed on a full marketplace where his friend was waiting. Most of the merchants called Da Vinci evil dragon or so and destroy and burned the machine. Da Vinci and his friend run off laughing. I am not sure but I am inclined to think that the story was part of a larger work related to Da Vinci’s fantastic anecdotes or tales. Have someone come across with this story?

Comment: The historic event was the flight of Leonardo da Vinci's "ornithopter" from Mt. Ceceri ("Hill of the Chickpea Swans") near Florence. Unfortunately Leonardo's estimates were incorrect; finding himself unable to fly, the pilot (Tommaso Masini, painter, astrologer and mathematician, nicknamed Zoroaster of Peretola) succeeded in controlled-gliding the thing and landing *almost* successfully in Fiesole, breaking a tibia and several ribs. This made Leonardo conclude that human-powered flight was not possible due to energy/weight constraints.